# Does java `SingleThreadExecutor` guarantee previous work is finished before new one starts?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

This is fragment of my code:

```
AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // work 1
    }
});

JSONArray apiResponseGet = ApiHelper.getInstance().getData();

if(apiResponseGet == null)
    throw new Exception("Api call failed");

AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // work 2
    }
});
```

What I except this code to do is to launch `work 1`, then, while `work 1` is executing, make request to api, and after api call finishes save it's results in `work 2`.
The problem  here is that `work 2` has to be executed after `work 1` is done. If `work 2` would start before `work 1` is finished, this could cause my app to misbehave.

Usually call to API will take much longer than `work 1`, but let's assume for now that api call has finished, and `work 1` is still running. Since diskIO is `SingleThreadExecutor`, does that mean, that since it's single thread, in this case `work 2` will have to wait until `work 1` finishes?
And if answer is no, how to make sure that when `work 2` starts, `work 1` is already done?

Comment: A quick look into Javadocs answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()):

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time.

So in your case `work 2` will have to wait until `work 1` finishes.